# S3 returning common prefixes for deleted objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I used aws cli to copy files to my bucket.

Keys

a/foo/foo.txt
b/bar/bar.txt

Then i used aws s3 rm command to empty the bucket and all objects has been removed.

But when i run this command

aws s3api list-objects —prefix a/ —delimiter /

Response has common prefixes as foo/

Any reason why s3 would stores prefixes after objects are deleted?

Comment: One reason could be that `deletes` have eventual consistency. So once you delete and then quickly check, the objects can still be there. It takes time for delete to propagate.

Comment: Its been more than couple hours now and same problem persists

Comment: Is your bucket versioned? I wonder if somehow `aws s3api list-objects` shows you delete markers or previous versions?

Comment: I dont think its the versioning or delete markers. When i have key as a/foo/ it returns keys as empty, assuming version should have foo.txt object.